# PHP no se muestra al generar PDF

Tags: php, html, pdf, mpdf

Estoy tratando de generar un pdf con datos recogidos en un formulario con PHP.
La libreria que estoy usando es mPDF

```html
<?php 

 $cliente = $_POST['cliente'];
 $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
 $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];

 require_once('pdf/mpdf.php');

 $html = '
    <div class="datos">
      <p> <?php echo $cliente; ?> </p>
      <p> <?php echo $direccion; ?> </p>
      <p> <?php echo $telefono; ?> </p>
    </div>';

 $mpdf = new mPDF('c', 'A4');
 $css = file_get_contents('css/pdf.css');
 $mpdf->writeHTML($css, 1);
 $mpdf->debug = true;
 $mpdf->writeHTML($html);
 $mpdf->Output('reporte.pdf', 'I');

 ?>
```

**A la hora de generar el pdf, me muestra el código PHP como texto plano. ¿Hay alguna forma de que muestre los datos dentros de las variables?**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes que cerrar la comilla (') después del primer párrafo <p>, porque lo está leyendo todo como HTML. Es decir, que tienes que concatenar el html y el php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que te ocurre es que estás enviando al documento texto cuyo contenido es código PHP, por lo que eso será lo que veas en su interior.

Para solucionarlo debes agregar los valores de las variables directamente a la cadena de texto de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php 

    $cliente = $_POST['cliente'];
    $direccion = $_POST['direccion'];
    $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];

    require_once('pdf/mpdf.php');

    $html = '
    <div class="datos">
      <p>' . htmlspecialchars($cliente) . '</p>
      <p>' . htmlspecialchars($direccion) . '</p>
      <p>' . htmlspecialchars($telefono) . '</p>
    </div>';

    $mpdf = new mPDF('c', 'A4');
    $css = file_get_contents('css/pdf.css');
    $mpdf->writeHTML($css, 1);
    $mpdf->debug = true;
    $mpdf->writeHTML($html);
    $mpdf->Output('reporte.pdf', 'I');
```

He usado [`htmlspecialchars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) para evitar que nombres, direcciones o teléfonos con caracteres que puedan confundirse con HTML rompan el diseño.